# How do transactions (technically) work?

Tags: transactions

I know what a transaction is and what its benefits and problems are - e.g., when talking about the ACID model in SQL-oriented databases. So far, so good.

But I'd like to understand how they technically work. I guess that there is a general pattern of how to make something transactional, whether it's a database or a file system. How do I make things atomic?

Unfortunately, when looking on Google for this, you find lots of articles that explain how to *use* transactions, but I do know that. I want to know *how* they work.

Any example, idea, link, paper or something (even a good term for searching myself) which points me in the right direction is welcome. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are based on two important concepts:

2 phase commit protocol
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol

and

2 phase locking
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking

Comment: Thanks for the links, they both explained perfectly what I wanted to know. So basically it always comes down to: 1. Do action, but mark as not-yet-completed, 2. ask all participants whether this worked, and 3. if so, commit or rollback.

Comment: exactly. thats the core concept